# How to show all x-axis labels of image.plot() without changing the size or alignment?

Tags: r, label

Not all x-axis labels of my image.plot() are displayed anymore when I increase the label size even though they would not yet overlap. Is there a way to force R to show all x-axis labels without decreasing the size or changing the alignment from horizontal to vertical?

```
library(fields)
library(dichromat)

zlim <- c(0.00, 13.47)
brks <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
color <- colorRampPalette(c("gray97", "gray28"))(15) 

image.plot(interp,
               zlim=zlim, add=T, verbose=F,
               col=color, breaks=brks, lab.breaks=brks,
               legend.only=T, horizontal=T, 
               legend.width=0.7,
               axis.args=list(cex.axis=1.4, font=2), 
               legend.mar=4.7,
               legend.args=list(text=("Anzahl heißer Tage (>30 °C) [Tage pro Jahr, T/J]"), 
                     cex=1.1, side=1, line=2.5, font=2))
```

[image: colorbar with the labels]

Answer (score 0):

Although the numbers wouldn't overlap, it would be difficult to discern the space between them, so it would be difficult to read. However, whether the numbers are suppressed is simply a matter of the size of the device you are using. If you resize the device the numbers will come and go.

For example, if I click on "zoom" in the Rstudio plot viewer, and shrink the window down, I get this result:

[image]

But if I make the window larger, I get this result:

[image]

So this has nothing to do with your code as such, it's just that your plotting device is too cramped. Make it larger and your problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I cannot just enlarge the device since the length of the bar is connected to the size of another plot. Together they have to fit a certain layout. That's why I am wondering if there is a way to just force the display of all labels regardless whether they might be difficult to discern or not.

Comment: @Luana so if you don't care that they are difficult to discern, why not make the text smaller?

Comment: @Luana or, as in my first example, have nice evenly spaced labels 2 or 3 apart. This is perfectly legible and much more aesthetically pleasing than trying to cram consecutive numbers together.

Comment: I think that I'll follow your second advice. Thanks again!